# CDbConnection and braces

Tags: php, mysql, yii, yii-components

Do a small component for my Yii app.
Code

```
$connection = Yii::app()->getComponent('db');
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM {{settings}}';
$command = $connection->createCommand($sql);
```

raises error

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an
>   error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
>   MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '{settings}}' at
>   line 1. The SQL statement executed was: SELECT * FROM {{settings}}

Tell me what went wrong. I can't use braces to escape the table name?

Thanks

**UPDATE:**

It seem this is Yii Query Bulduer bug.

if I use this configuration

```
'db'=>array(
    'connectionString' => '...',
    'emulatePrepare' => ...,
    'username' => '...',
    'password' => '...',
    'charset' => '...',
    'tablePrefix' => ''
),
```

pay attention to the empty tablePrefix — all works fine.

Removing this key I get the problem described above. But I don't need table prefix. I just want to use a component that can work with prefixes, not only in my application.

Comment: eggyal, my table name is settings

Comment: I use v1.1.14. error occurs only if no tablePrefix key

Comment: The ability to use empty table prefixes was raised in [issue 1931](https://code.google.com/p/yii/issues/detail?id=1931): this was supposedly fixed in [revision 2780](https://code.google.com/p/yii/source/detail?r=2780), which was [included in v1.1.6](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii/blob/1.1.6/CHANGELOG#L41).  I can't explain why it isn't working for you, as `CDbCommand::setText()` [should replace non-null prefixes](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii/blob/1.1.14/framework/db/CDbCommand.php#L172).  Are you *absolutely sure* you're using 1.1.14?

Comment: eggyal, yes, my version is 1.1.14

Comment: maybe a weird question, but why you don't use ``` to escape the table name? like ususally done in MySQL ?

Comment: @Asped: This is Yii feature: see [Using Table Prefix](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.dao#using-table-prefix).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry, I've just realised what your update actually says.

> if I use this configuration
>
> ```
> 'db'=>array(
>     'connectionString' => '...',
>     'emulatePrepare' => ...,
>     'username' => '...',
>     'password' => '...',
>     'charset' => '...',
>     'tablePrefix' => ''
> ),
> ```
>
> pay attention to the empty tablePrefix — all works fine.

Yes, of course it does: you have defined `tablePrefix` to be an empty string (and, as I already [pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23581123/cdbconnection-and-braces#comment36198831_23581123), empty-string prefixes have been [supported](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii/blob/1.1.6/CHANGELOG#L41) since v.1.1.6).

> Removing this key I get the problem described above. But I don't need table prefix. I just want to use a component that can work with prefixes, not only in my application.

If you don't define `tablePrefix`, then comparing it against `null` will be true (and as I also pointed out before, `CDbCommand::setText()` [replaces non-null prefixes](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii/blob/1.1.14/framework/db/CDbCommand.php#L172)):

```
if($this->_connection->tablePrefix!==null && $value!='')
    $this->_text=preg_replace('/{{(.*?)}}/',$this->_connection->tablePrefix.'\1',$value);
```

Thus you must either replace braces yourself or else explicitly set `tablePrefix` to be the empty string.  If you have no control over the configuration file, but want to ensure that `tablePrefix` is set, you could manually override it:

```
if (!isset($connection->tablePrefix)) $connection->tablePrefix = '';
```